# Editing Specific Edit control in a program

Tags: c#

Is there any way to get a specific Edit control instance HWND? As i am able to get the main window HWND, but having trouble getting this specific control HWND.

EDIT:

So i managed to set the text of the edit control using it's handle, now my question is it possible to set the text using its ID?

```
private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    HandleRef hWnd, 
    uint Msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    string lParam);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr MytestHandle = new IntPtr(0x00030670);
    HandleRef hrefHWndTarget = new HandleRef(null, MytestHandle);
    SendMessage(hrefHWndTarget, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "text");
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with _Control.Handle_?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The control is from another application

Comment: `SetDlgItemText`